# How to use an array index sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop

Consider the following code of which I manually typed out because I did not know a more efficient (less lines approach):

```
$('div.mrSingle:eq(0)').closest('td').addClass("yellow").css("background-color", "");
$('div.mrSingle:eq(1)').closest('td').addClass("lightgreen").css("background-color", "");
$('div.mrSingle:eq(2)').closest('td').addClass("green").css("background-color", "");
$('div.mrSingle:eq(3)').closest('td').addClass("skyblue").css("background-color", "");
$('div.mrSingle:eq(4)').closest('td').addClass("blue").css("background-color", "");
```

How do I, in both JavaScript and jQuery, create an array that goes yellow, lightgreen, green, skyblue and blue?  Then, how do I iterate through a specific set of DOM elements and apply said array to the DOM element index so as to automatically add the array index *name* as the class of the DOM element?

```js
$('div.mrSingle:eq(0)').closest('td').addClass("yellow").css("background-color", "");
$('div.mrSingle:eq(1)').closest('td').addClass("lightgreen").css("background-color", "");
$('div.mrSingle:eq(2)').closest('td').addClass("green").css("background-color", "");
$('div.mrSingle:eq(3)').closest('td').addClass("skyblue").css("background-color", "");
$('div.mrSingle:eq(4)').closest('td').addClass("blue").css("background-color", "");
```

```css
   .yellow {background-color: #FFFF00;width: 186px;}
   .lightgreen {background-color: #CCFF66;width: 186px;}
   .green {background-color: #00B050;width: 186px;}
   .skyblue {background-color: #00FFCC;width: 186px;}
   .blue {background-color: #00B0F0;width: 186px;}
   .E62 {width: 930px; border-collapse: collapse; border: solid 1px #000; margin: 0 auto;}
   .E62 td {border: solid 1px #000;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="E62">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="yellow" colspan="2">Products from a manufacturer using vial caps with distinct colors for each of their vaccines shown on a shelf. The newly launched product with a green cap (in front) is from a different manufacturer from the one in the yellow carton and duplicates
        one of the existing colors.</td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="blue" colspan="2">Products from a manufacturer using consistent vial cap colors for all of their vaccines shown on a shelf. The newly launched vial with a green cap (in front) is from a different manufacturer and does not duplicate the existing colors because the
        existing products all have matching white caps.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="Cell.1.0" class="mrGridQuestionText yellow" style="text-Align: Center;vertical-align: Bottom;width: 120px;border-color: black;border-style: Solid;border-width: 1px;">
        <span class="mrQuestionText" style="font-size: 9pt;"><b>Much less likely</b> to create confusion<span id="yellow"></span></span>
      </td>
      <td id="Cell.2.0" class="mrGridQuestionText lightgreen" style="text-Align: Center;vertical-align: Bottom;width: 120px;border-color: black;border-style: Solid;border-width: 1px;">
        <span class="mrQuestionText" style="font-size: 9pt;"><b>Somewhat less likely</b> to create confusion<span id="lightgreen"></span></span>
      </td>
      <td id="Cell.3.0" class="mrGridQuestionText green" style="text-Align: Center;vertical-align: Bottom;width: 120px;border-color: black;border-style: Solid;border-width: 1px;">
        <span class="mrQuestionText" style="font-size: 9pt;"><b>Equally likely</b> to create confusion<span id="green"></span></span>
      </td>
      <td id="Cell.4.0" class="mrGridQuestionText skyblue" style="text-Align: Center;vertical-align: Bottom;width: 120px;border-color: black;border-style: Solid;border-width: 1px;">
        <span class="mrQuestionText" style="font-size: 9pt;"><b>Somewhat less likely</b> to create confusion<span id="skyblue"></span></span>
      </td>
      <td id="Cell.5.0" class="mrGridQuestionText blue" style="text-Align: Center;vertical-align: Bottom;width: 120px;border-color: black;border-style: Solid;border-width: 1px;">
        <span class="mrQuestionText" style="font-size: 9pt;"><b>Much less likely</b> to create confusion<span id="blue"></span></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td id="Cell.1.1" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width: 120px; border: 1px solid black;" class="yellow">
        <div style="width: 100px;"></div>
        <div class="mrSingle styledRadio" style="width: 100%; height: 27px; cursor: pointer; background-image: url(&quot;https://s.rrimr.com/ui/screwdefaultbuttons/images/radioVerySmall.png&quot;); background-position: 50% -54px;">
          <input type="radio" name="_QGRE62_Q__01_QE62_C" id="_Q0_Q0_Q0_C0" class="mrSingle" disabled="" style="display: none;" value="__01">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td id="Cell.2.1" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width: 120px; border: 1px solid black;" class="lightgreen">
        <div style="width: 100px;"></div>
        <div class="mrSingle styledRadio" style="width: 100%; height: 27px; cursor: pointer; background-image: url(&quot;https://s.rrimr.com/ui/screwdefaultbuttons/images/radioVerySmall.png&quot;); background-position: 50% -54px;">
          <input type="radio" name="_QGRE62_Q__01_QE62_C" id="_Q0_Q0_Q0_C1" class="mrSingle" disabled="" style="display: none;" value="__02">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td id="Cell.3.1" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width: 120px; border: 1px solid black;" class="green">
        <div style="width: 100px;"></div>
        <div class="mrSingle styledRadio" style="width: 100%; height: 27px; cursor: pointer; background-image: url(&quot;https://s.rrimr.com/ui/screwdefaultbuttons/images/radioVerySmall.png&quot;); background-position: 50% -54px;">
          <input type="radio" name="_QGRE62_Q__01_QE62_C" id="_Q0_Q0_Q0_C2" class="mrSingle" disabled="" style="display: none;" value="__03">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td id="Cell.4.1" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width: 120px; border: 1px solid black;" class="skyblue">
        <div style="width: 100px;"></div>
        <div class="mrSingle styledRadio" style="width: 100%; height: 27px; cursor: pointer; background-image: url(&quot;https://s.rrimr.com/ui/screwdefaultbuttons/images/radioVerySmall.png&quot;); background-position: 50% -54px;">
          <input type="radio" name="_QGRE62_Q__01_QE62_C" id="_Q0_Q0_Q0_C3" class="mrSingle" disabled="" style="display: none;" value="__04">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td id="Cell.5.1" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width: 120px; border: 1px solid black;" class="blue">
        <div style="width: 100px;"></div>
        <div class="mrSingle styledRadio" style="width: 100%; height: 27px; cursor: pointer; background-image: url(&quot;https://s.rrimr.com/ui/screwdefaultbuttons/images/radioVerySmall.png&quot;); background-position: 50% -54px;">
          <input type="radio" name="_QGRE62_Q__01_QE62_C" id="_Q0_Q0_Q0_C4" class="mrSingle" disabled="" style="display: none;" value="__05">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My goal/hope is to be able to declare the array in **1 line** and then use the `.each()` method to apply the corresponding class in **1 line**, so as to have this documented for future reference and a best practice guideline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
colors = ['yellow','lightgreen','green','skyblue','blue'];
colors.forEach(function(color, index){
    $('div.mrSingle:eq('+index+')').closest('td').addClass(color).css("background-color", "");
});
```

or, a little cleaner using jQuery each:

```
colors = ['yellow','lightgreen','green','skyblue','blue'];
$('.mrSingle').each(function(index, element){
     element.closest('td').addClass(colors[index]);
});
```

Comment: *How do I, in both **JavaScript** and jQuery*.....for what it's worth, seems like the OP wanted both

Comment: @DelightedD0D jQuery is JavaScript. I'm not going to give this guy a crash course on JS right now,  and my answer is a good starting point for figuring the rest out.

Notice the phrasing of his question... "How do I, in both JavaScript and jQuery, create an array that goes yellow, lightgreen, green, skyblue and blue" ... The answer is the same... `colors = [...]`

Comment: How did you just pull the _color_ variable out of thin air without declaring it? Does JS know what you meant?

Comment: @AlexanderDixon in JS `array.forEach` always returns a callback that has the current element of the array and the current index as variables, i just gave it the name `color`... so in general, `array.forEach(function(item_in_array, index_in_array){   })` where function gets call *for each* element of an array. Let me know if you want a deeper explanation!

Comment: the jQuery `element.closest` is throwing a console log error.  I know that I can simply use `$(this)`, bust just to know, how do we pass in the parameter of the function correctly as the current syntax does not work.

Comment: @AlexanderDixon sorry i don't ever use .each so I'm not exactly sure what the problem is. What is the error? You should get used to searching and posting specific error messages, it is usually very helpful! Also why not just use $(this)